# Sending data over Wifi from Android App to Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to create an Android app that can send a confirmation message, either a string or an encrypted signal, over WiFi to my raspberry pi connected to the same WiFi network. How can I achieve this task?

The raspberry pi is running on raspbian. Do I need to code a separate app on the pi to receive the message?

Comment: Yes you need a server or client on your raspi. And a client or server on your Android device. Communication always goes by client/server.

Comment: If you let the raspi be the server then program the server in python or C using sockets. For Android app just use java and use a socket to connect to server on raspi.

Comment: Of course you can install a webserver on the raspi too and write some php scripts. On Android device you use classes or libraries to communicate in http.

Answer (score 1):

1. How do you connect to your RaspberryPI? Does it have static IP?
2. You need kind of server on RaspberryPI which can listen what your Android device sends (I suggest you simple NodeJS server, easy to install, work, modify).

P.S.: provide more details and I can give you some suggestions, a month ago I did a project where connected Android app with RaspberryPI through Firebase.

Comment: The RaspBerry Pi is connected to the same Wifi Network as the Android Device. No, it has dynamic IP.

Comment: How do you catch RaspberryPI IP? Do you put manually in Android app?

Comment: It's OK, so for now you should install NodeJS on your RaspberryPI. Then install simple Node server: https://github.com/resin-io-projects/simple-server-node and put in console.log data from request, in RaspberryPI terminal you will be able to see what you sent from Android app.

Comment: Ok to make sure I understand it correctly, the server will be on raspberry pi listening to anything that is being sent to it's url?

And on the Android app side, how do I send information to the server?

Comment: And apparently it requires resinOS? I need to work on raspbian though

Comment: yes, you understand it correctly. On Android side you suppose to have application which sends data to RaspberryPI. This app can be done in native (you should write in Java) or hybrid (Ionic framework http://ionicframework.com/, HTML/JS).

Comment: If you need an example of implementation then provide which data you wanna send and what do you want to do on RaspberryPI side and then I can make some code and publish on github.

Comment: ok for example. On the android app, after a user authenticates via login, the app is supposed to send a unique hash over to the pi to indicate login successful and who is the one logging in, using the unique hash sent over. So for now I just need to figure out the sending and receiving part on the pi. Thanks so much.

Comment: `On the android app, after a user authenticates via login, `. Where would it login? Is there a third party in play?

Comment: no, it just logins in-app. You can skip this phase, it's just an example

Comment: @PetroGordiyevich Hey sorry but just a quick check with you regarding sending message from PC to Rpi through WiFi hotspot. I already set up my Rpi with a static IP and port. From my Java application, I managed to open connection. But when I tried to send a message from PC to Rpi through the WiFi hotspot, the message didn't went through. Do you have any ideas how it actually works?

Comment: @hyperfkcb can you ping your Rpi from PC?

Comment: @PetroGordiyevich What would you suggest in case of a File tranfer from android to Raspberry Pi. I am working on an application which should connct to the RPi HotSpot. Once a connection is established, a file has to be pushed from the android app to the RPi. My question is, from which side should the file transfer be initiated? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @SanketMendon consider about RPi app as a server and Android as a client. So, your server app is listening to a certain port and Android app sending POST/PUT request and file attached as a parameter. RPi app receives this request (possible validate) and saves a file somewhere on RPi storage. I suggest you use libs for doing this, which exactly I can not tell now because no enough information what do you use for server and for client.